# PSQL - Aggregating Sales Data by Timeframe

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out a better way to write my scripts. Lately, I have found myself relying on Left Joins to accomplish a lot of what I need and I'm wondering if there is a better way to be writing my scripts.

Below is a quick example of what I have been trying, let me know what you think.

```
SELECT a.id,
       SUM(a.spend) AS spend,
       SUM(a.revenue) AS revenue,
       SUM(b.spend) AS spend,
       SUM(b.revenue),
       c.product_name
FROM (SELECT client, name FROM table_1) AS ACC
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT revenue, spend, id FROM table_2 WHERE MONTH = 11) AS a ON acc.id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT revenue, spend, id FROM table_2 WHERE MONTH = 10) AS b ON acc.id = b.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_name FROM table_3) ON a.id = c.id
ORDER BY a.spend
```

Comment: could you just use case expressions? `sum(case when month =11 then spend else 0 end) as Spend11, sum(case when month = 11 then revenue else 0 end) as Revenue11...`  eliminating all the left joins?  or analytic sum(case when month=11 then spend else 0 end) over (partition by product_name) as Spend11...

Comment: Thanks for the post xQvert, SUM(case when) I think could also work. I don't generally use them because I have been trying to use subqueries more lately. That could be a classic rookie mistake though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those derived tables (aka subquery or inline view). You are also missing a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT a.id,
       SUM(a.spend) AS spend,
       SUM(a.revenue) AS revenue,
       SUM(b.spend) AS spend,
       SUM(b.revenue),
       c.product_name
FROM table_1 AS ACC
  LEFT JOIN table_2 AS a ON acc.id = a.id AND a.MONTH = 11 
  LEFT JOIN table_2 AS b ON acc.id = b.id AND b.MONTH = 10
  LEFT JOIN table_3 AS c ON a.id = c.id
GROUP BY a.id, c.product_name
```

Another option is to use filtered aggregation:

```
SELECT a.id,
       SUM(a.spend) filter (where a.month = 11) AS spend_11,
       SUM(a.revenue) filter (where a.month = 11 AS revenue_11,
       SUM(a.spend) filter (where a.month = 10) AS spend_10,
       SUM(a.revenue) filter (where a.month = 10) as revenue_10,
       c.product_name
FROM table_1 AS ACC
  LEFT JOIN table_2 AS a ON acc.id = a.id AND a.MONTH in (10,11)
  LEFT JOIN table_3 AS c ON a.id = c.id
GROUP BY a.id, c.product_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the post a_horse_with_no_name. Let me give this a try and see how it works!